# Bad credentials - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual necesito hacer un login que funcione con jwt, probando todo en localhost lo habia logrado hacer andar, de hecho anda inclusive ahora, consumiendo los datos desde una base de datos postgress, pero al momento de hacer un deploy por ejemplo en heroku, y tratar de hacer un login, en consola me tira un error de Bad credentials. Tanto el local como la subida a heroku estan conectadas a la misma base de datos(es remota, no local) sin embargo en una funciona y en otra no.

Este es mi **AuthController.java**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.prueba.final.model.ERole;
import com.prueba.final.model.Role;
import com.prueba.final.model.User;
import com.prueba.final.payload.request.LoginRequest;
import com.prueba.final.payload.request.SignupRequest;
import com.prueba.final.payload.response.JwtResponse;
import com.prueba.final.payload.response.MessageResponse;
import com.prueba.final.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
import com.prueba.final.service.RoleRepositoryService;
import com.prueba.final.service.UserDetailsImpl;
import com.prueba.final.service.UserRepositoryService;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {
  @Autowired
  AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Autowired
  UserRepositoryService userRepository;

  @Autowired
  RoleRepositoryService roleRepository;

  @Autowired
  PasswordEncoder encoder;

  @Autowired
  JwtUtils jwtUtils;

  @PostMapping("/signin")
  public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
    System.out.println(loginRequest.getUsername());
    System.out.println(loginRequest.getPassword());
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
        .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(authentication);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt,
        userDetails.getId(),
        userDetails.getUsername(),
        roles));
  }

  @PostMapping("/signup")
  public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {
    if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
      return ResponseEntity
          .badRequest()
          .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
    }
    User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(),
        encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

    Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    if (strRoles == null) {
      Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
          .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
      roles.add(userRole);
    } else {
      strRoles.forEach(role -> {
        switch (role) {
          case "admin":
            Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(adminRole);

            break;
          case "mod":
            Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(modRole);

            break;
          default:
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        }
      });
    }

    user.setRoles(roles);
    userRepository.save(user);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
  }
}
```

Este es mi model **User.java**

```
package com.prueba.final.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "zz_users", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username")
})
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @NotBlank
  @Size(max = 20)
  private String username;
  private String password;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "zz_user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
  private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

  public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

  public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

  public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
  
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

  public User() {
  }
  
}
```

Mi model **User.java**

```
package com.prueba.final.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "zz_roles")
public class Role {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(length = 20)
  private ERole name;

  public Role(ERole name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public ERole getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(ERole name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Role() {
  }
}
```

Este es mi **LoginRequest.java**

```
package com.prueba.final.payload.request;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

public class LoginRequest {
  @NotBlank
  private String username;

  @NotBlank
  private String password;

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

Este es mi **JwtResponse.java**

```
package com.prueba.final.payload.response;

import java.util.List;

public class JwtResponse {
  private String token;
  private String type = "Bearer";
  private Long id;
  private String username;
  private List<String> roles;

  public JwtResponse(String accessToken, Long id, String username, List<String> roles) {
    this.token = accessToken;
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.roles = roles;
  }

  public String getAccessToken() {
    return token;
  }

  public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
    this.token = accessToken;
  }

  public String getTokenType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
    this.type = tokenType;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public List<String> getRoles() {
    return roles;
  }
}
```

Este es mi **AuthEntryPointJwt.java**

```
package com.prueba.final.security.jwt;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint{
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);
  @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Este es mi **AuthTokenFilter.java**

```
package com.prueba.final.security.jwt;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.prueba.final.service.UserDetailsServiceImplement;

public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  @Autowired
  private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsServiceImplement userDetailsService;
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      String jwt = parseJwt(request);
      if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
        String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
      return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Este es mi **JwtUtils**

```
package com.prueba.final.security.jwt;

import java.util.Date;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.prueba.final.service.UserDetailsImpl;

import io.jsonwebtoken.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class JwtUtils {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

  @Value("${zebelek.app.jwtSecret}")
  private String jwtSecret;

  @Value("${zebelek.app.jwtExpirationMs}")
  private int jwtExpirationMs;

  public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {
    UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

    return Jwts.builder()
      .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
      .setIssuedAt(new Date())
      .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
      .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
      .compact();
  }

  public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
  }

  public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
    try {
      Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
      return true;
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
      logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
      logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
      logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
      logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Y este es mi **WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.prueba.final.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.prueba.final.security.jwt.AuthEntryPointJwt;
import com.prueba.final.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter;
import com.prueba.final.service.UserDetailsServiceImplement;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
  @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImplement userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;
    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        security
          .httpBasic().disable()
          .formLogin().disable()
          .cors().and().csrf().disable()
          .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
          .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
          .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/api/data/**").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated();
          security.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Problema de la base de datos no creo que sea porque recibe modifica y agrega otros datos, y funciona bien, pero el login solo lo logre hacer funcionar desde localhost, desde heroku no importa que haga me dice **Bad Credentials**

Answer (score 0):

he visto este codigo antes, seria muy util que agregaras como esta haciendose el request, es decir, activa las herramientas de desarrollador en el navegador y analiza los headers y los parametros. tambien de ser posible dockeriza y pasa a un contenedor de kubernetes para que obtengas un comportamiento similar al que obtendras al desplegar en remoto.

En mi caso estaba leyendo el jwt de una cookie y lo estaba enviando en un cabecero, por eso nunca coincidian las credenciales.